# Solution of 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the following ordinary differential equation (ODE) analytically?

$$ a(u)\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)^2 \frac{da(u)}{du}+b =0$$

Comment: First, this is not a partial differential equation (it is an ordinary differential equation). Second, non-linear differential equations don't usually have analytic solutions. Why do you think an analytic solution exists? Show your work.

Comment: Yes, actually , I want to find the solution equation (20) in this paper, that form is general form for equation (20) in this paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6778020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a primitive of $a$, then
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}A(u(x))=\frac{d}{dx}a(u(x))u'(x)=a(u)u''(x)+a'(u)u'(x)^2.
$$
This fits exactly the first two terms of your equation, so
$$
A(u(x))=-\frac{b}{2}x^2+cx+d.
$$

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer, but how can I get the x in that equation?

Comment: I do not understand. As it is, it is an implicit equation for the values of $u$. $b$ is the constant from the equation, $c,d$ get their values from the initial condition.